# Track selected radio button and apply style on the fly

Tags: jquery, css, radio-button

I need to track which radio button is checked and add/remove style to it.

How to detect which radio button is checked at the moment.
I can track only what is checked by default when user opened the page.

Can somebody help with the code and share links to further readings about methods used.

Big Thanks!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/ I think this can help you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **change event**

```
var $radio = $('input[type="radio"]');

$radio.on('change', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    this.checked ? $this.addClass('a') : $this.removeClass('a');
    $radio.not(this).removeClass('a');
});
```

**[check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/e955Q/)**

Comment: @jonnypixel.. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery :checked can do this for you. Loop through your radio inputs(With `each`, also jQuery) and look for the checked input.

Something like this(untested):

```
jQuery.each('.radio_inputs', function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).addClass('.checked_input');
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/ and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: Thanks for this. I will check it as well. Seems straightforward. But I suppose it will not be able to track change?

Comment: No it will not. But on a change you won't have to loop through all the inputs. I wasn't aware of the fact you wanted it onChange ;-) You can use the innerpart though, just change the .each for `$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() { //code here });`